# Como inserir uma ação para fechar o Drawer automaticamente?

Tags: flutter

Este é o código

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Drawer(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Text("Header", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html):

> An open drawer can be closed by calling Navigator.pop.

Isto é, traduzindo livremente, uma Drawer aberta pode ser fechada chamando `Navigator.pop()`

No seu código, não existe nenhum componente que possa capturar esse toque, para ter uma função que rode esse comando.

Você pode colocar um [Gesture Detector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), por exemplo. Ou seguir o exemplo da documentação e utilizar após a Drawer Header, uma [List tile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), que já tem a propriedade `onTap()`:

Pegando o seu exemplo de código e usando uma listTile:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Drawer(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Text("Header", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
              ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.change_history),
                  title: Text('Change history'),
                  onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context); // Fecha a gaveta.
                  },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Ótimo! Resolvido. Obrigado!